# Handle database in kivy android app

Tags: android, python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, kivy

i'm trying to create a simple android app and i need to save some data.

kivy storage api does't fit my needs (it will grow on complexity) and i choose sqlalchemy+sqlite.

i need to initialize the db only on the first start of the app, and here's my code... works on pc, but not on android -.-

```
import os.path
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=False)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class Entry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entries'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Entry %r>' % (self.name)

def init_db():
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


class AddEntryForm(BoxLayout):
    add_entry_input = ObjectProperty()
    add_entry_results = ObjectProperty()

    def add_entry(self):
        if self.add_entry_input.text != "":
            new_item = Entry(self.add_entry_input.text)
            if not session.query(Entry).filter_by(name=self.add_entry_input.text).first():
                session.add(new_item)
                session.commit()
            self.add_entry_results.item_strings = [d.name for d in session.query(Entry).order_by("name").all()]
            self.add_entry_input.text = ""


class EntryTrkrApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.path.exists("test.db"):
        init_db()
    EntryTrkrApp().run()
```

it's my very first kivy app and also my first android app; it's just a test, but i want to learn, so every advice will be great :)

thanks all!

Comment: you have to store android data to specific locations ... (the sdcard is a pretty safe bet ... I think kivy makes it avaible in some variable) why doesnt the storage api meet your needs? what are your needs? what makes you think sqlite will do better?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely that the working directory is not writable. A traceback or log output would be helpful to confirm (you can get this from logcat, i.e. `buildozer android logcat`, or `adb logcat` if you aren't using buildozer).

You can use the `platform` variable (`from kivy import platform`) to see if you are running on android and set the location to the sdcard or app data storage. Note that you may want to do something to standardize the location of the database file on desktop as well (unless you want to always use a file in the working directory).

This should provide a writable directory (untested though):

```
from jnius import autoclass
PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
writable_directory = PythonActivity.mActivity.getFilesDir()
```

Comment: I'm not sure, and it doesn't matter because that shouldn't be relied upon. The 'proper' approach is to use the methods provided by the OS for this purpose, i.e. `Context.getFilesDir()` or the `Environment` storage methods.